# Html Helper in partial view, only adding my script once

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a view that is rendering multiple partial view inside as follow :

```
<div>
    <table class="EditTable">
        @foreach (var view in Model.ViewsToRender)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100%;">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/TC2/Views/Shared/" + view.Name + ".cshtml", view.viewModel)
                </td>
            </tr>    
        }

    </table>

</div>
```

Each view is doing almost the same rendering :  content and adding a js script to show/hide the block :

```
@{
    var classShow = "show_hide" + Model.Name;
    @Html.AddShowScriptConsult(classShow);
}

<div id="viewContent">
    <div class="viewTitle">@Model.Name</div>
    <i class="@classShow fa fa-minus-circle buttonExtended"></i>
    <div>My html content ....</div>
</div>
```

It is working fine, except that my helper is only called once for the first view, and the other partial view didnt add the script to show/hide the unit. It seems like this line : "@Html.AddShowScriptConsult(classShow);" is only called once for all the partial view, I expected it to be called once for each view, since the call is inside each partial view within "Model.ViewsToRender".

If you need further informations or clarifications don't be afraid to ask, I simplified my code due to company policy but this example represent perfectly my problem.

Comment: Could you try to us `Child Action` that simply return the view instead of partial call of the view. this is the approach I follow generally and it work fine for me.

Comment: I dont understand how I can render my view with "Action" since I'm not calling any controller here

Comment: Create new Controller for your partial view, create an action and decorate it with `[ChildActionOnly]`. let the action return the partial view. on the View call the action and let it handle the partial view rendering

Comment: Hmmm yeah but I have to do it for every view in Model.ViewsToRender which is dynamycaly fill so I can't really do this I guess